# Approximation of an Itô integral without using code

Tags: stochastic-calculus, approximation, stochastic-integrals

> **Exercise 3.11** (Approximation of an Itô Integral).
> In this example, the stochastic integral $\int^t_0tW(t)dW(t)$ is considered. The expected value of the integral and the expected value of the square of the integral are estimated using $M=1,000,000$ sample paths. The number of intervals used on $[0,1]$ is $N$ where $N=4,8,16,\dots,256$. The preceding approximate method is used, which for this problem, has the explicit form
> \begin{align*}
> E((I(f))^\alpha)&=E\left(\int^1_0tW(t)dW(t)\right)^\alpha\\
> &\approx\frac{1}{M}\sum^M_{j=1}\left(\sum^{N-1}_{i=0}t_i^{(N)}W^{(j)}(t_i^{(N)})(W^{(j)}(t^{(N)}_{t+1})-W^{(j)}(t^{(N)}_i))\right)^\alpha\quad(2)\\
> \end{align*}
> for $\alpha=1$ or $2$ and $t_i^{(N)}=i/N$ for $i=0,1,2,\dots,N$. Notice that $(W^{(j)}(t^{(N)}_{i+1})-W^{(j)}(t_i^{(N)}))=\eta_i^{(j)}/\sqrt{N}$ where $\eta_i^{(j)}\sim N(0,1)$ and also that $(W^{(j)}(t^{(N)}_{i})-W^{(j)}(t_{i-1}^{(N)}))=\eta_{i-1}^{(j)}/\sqrt{N}$. A computer program that performs this calculation is listed at the end of this chapter. The calculational results are given in Table 3.2 for $M=1,000,000$ sample paths. Notice that the results improve as $N$ increases. The exact values are $E(I(f))=0$ and $E((I(f))^2)=0.25.$
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> \hline
> \text{Value of N}&|E(I(f))|&|E((I(f))^2)|\\
> \hline
> \color{red}{2^2}&\color{red}{0.00107}&\color{red}{0.14071}\\
> 2^3&0.00012&0.19151\\
> 2^4&0.00069&0.21906\\
> 2^5&0.00038&0.23508\\
> 2^6&0.00007&0.24209\\
> 2^7&0.00001&0.24486\\
> 2^8&0.00002&0.24821\\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> Source: [Modeling with Itô Stochastic Differential Equations by Edward Allen, pg. 74](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4020-5953-7.pdf?pdf=button)

### My Question

There is a code provided on pg. 87, but I would like to calculate the value $N$, specifically $2^2$ for $|E(I(f))|$and$|E((I(f))^2)$ above in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$, manually. My assumption is to use $\text{(2)}$ to get these values, but I'm unsure where to begin.

Would anybody be able to provide a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must use a gaussian random number generator, since $W^{(j)}(t_i^{(N)}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t_i^{(N)})$, with $t_i^{(N)} = \frac{i}{N}$, and then you must simply apply Eq. (2) for $N = 2$ straighforwardly.

Nevertheless, I don't know what you expect. If you mean 'manually' as *by hand*, it won't be feasible, because the sums include millions of terms and draws. If you intend to reproduce the results *by yourself* (but with a computer), your own computations can still lead to (close but) different values, since the outcomes of a random variable are by nature... random.

Notwithstanding, the moments of the considered stochastic process, namely $X_t = \int_0^t sW_s \,\mathrm{d}W_s$, can be determined analytically. Indeed, one has $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = 0$, since $W_s$ and $\mathrm{d}W_s$ are independent and have zero mean, while Itô's isometry gives
$$
\mathrm{Var}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[X_t^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t s^2W_s^2 \,\mathrm{d}s\right] = \int_0^t s^2\,\mathbb{E}[W_s^2] \,\mathrm{d}s = \int_0^t s^3 \,\mathrm{d}s = \frac{1}{4}t^4,
$$
which is equal to $1/4$ when $t=1$.

Comment: +1 Fantastic reply! This is exactly what I needed. Two additional questions, if you have a moment: 1) would a gaussian random number generator in python or R would suffice here for $U(0;1)$, or would I need to use a specific method? 2) My understanding is that Kiyosi Itô published his seminal papers from 1938 and 1945, but how were such SDEs approximated prior to modern computers?

Comment: Computers usually produce pseudo-random numbers; I must admit that I don't know whether Python's or R's seeds are of good quality or not.

Comment: Back in time, such SDEs were mainly employed for the description of physical phenomena, as the well-known Brownian motion for instance, that is why they didn't need to generate random numbers, so that the mean and the variance were directly from the observational data. In other words, the nature was the real random number generator through random phenomena. The production of random numbers becomes a problem only in pure mathematics; tables or randomly generated numbers, established by sophisticated dice throws for example, were actually available (in the same way as tables of logarithms).

Comment: I had a query about which python code would be the most intuitive to find the approximations in the table. I've attempted to use the following code found in $\texttt{In [5]}$: [here](https://notebook.community/IanHawke/HighamSDEs/Stochastic%20DEs), but to no avail. In the textbook, the author uses the Fortran program.